# Referencing drafts for editing

Tags: vba, outlook, edit

I'm trying to edit drafts in Outlook: subject, body, send to, etc.

I get how to create new mail, but how would I edit a draft. Not looking for whole code, just something to help me get started.

Comment: start new email message and save   ..... web search "vba outlook new message save"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean how to open an existing email in the Drafts folder? Open the Drafts folder using `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)`. The items can be accessed using the `MAPIFolder.Items` collection.

Comment: Yes; thanks, that's what I was the main thing I was trying to figure out.